# Enable field only when the other field input is done

Tags: angular, typescript

I set the last name field to be disabled. How to go about making it enable only when the first name is been inputted.

```
 <form>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" disabled>
    </form>
```

Comment: angular version ?

Comment: Yes @shashanksharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

**component.ts**

```
 user: any = {
    fname : '',
    lname: ''
  };
```

**component.html**

```
<form name="myform" #formdemo="ngForm">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname"  class="form-control" #fname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.fname" name="fname"  required/><br>


    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)]="user.lname"  name="lname" [attr.disabled]="fname.hasError('required') ? true : null" required/><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-template-form-validation

Comment: Hi. The answer was very helpful. I Checked the stackblitz. Can we get the Last name to clear the input when it's been disabled again? For now, the previously entered value in the last name field is shown when you clear the first name field.

Comment: yes we can clear last name if first name is empty. Here is demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-template-form-validation

Comment: Cool. I did something different though and it works as well. I added onfocus="this.value=''". However, your method functions pretty much very well. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a dropdown select button to the initial stackblitz you provided.  How to I disabled the Description of Car Fields until a dropdown value is selected? https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-template-form-validation-ragakw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7276310/santosh-shinde

Comment: Here is stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-angular-template-form-validation-3mp6hz

Answer (score 0):

**See working example..**

```js
function showMe(e) {
  if(e.value.length > 0){
    $("#lname").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
  else{
    $("#lname").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onkeyup="showMe(this)"><br>
   <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" disabled>
</form>
```